# GDB: print passed variable in Fortran subroutine

Tags: gdb, fortran90

I am debugging prog.f90, which has a module mod.f90. 
How do I print the argument variable values?

The module has a subroutine that gets called within a loop. It takes in the arguments, stores one in a local variable, calculates the new value of the argument, stores that in another local variable, then uses the local variables to test a certain condition. The new value of the argument gets passed back to main.

I am trying to print the values of all the variables while within the subroutine.
I can print the local variables, but printing the argument variables gives me a reference address.

```
(gdb)print temp_curr
$1 = 4
(gdb)print arg1
$2 = (REF TO -> ( real8 )) @0x7fffffffe0a0: -nan(0x8000000000000)
```

I tried...

```
(gdb)print $arg1
$3 = VOID
```

The subroutine looks something like this...

```
SUBROUTINE sub(arg1, arg2)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL, INTENT(inout):: arg1, arg2
REAL               :: temp_prev, temp_curr

temp_prev = arg1

arg1 = (a bunch of calculations)/arg2

temp_curr = arg1

IF (temp_curr < temp_prev) THEN
    stop
END IF

END SUBROUTINE sub
```

Comment: It looks like you should be able to dereference that variables using C syntax: http://numericalnoob.blogspot.be/2012/08/fortran-allocatable-arrays-and-pointers.html

Comment: I tried this without success:    `(gdb) print *((real *) ecc)
Cannot access memory at address 0x3fe999999999999a`

Answer (score 0):

The `$arg1` variable in gdb is used only in gdb scrips (see [GDB documentation](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Define.html#Define)). If you refer to the variable of the program being debugged use only `arg1`.

Try `print MODULENAME::VARNAME` if you want to print a variable (VARNAME) from another module (MODULENAME)